# Windows 8 metro application access arbitrary file path

Tags: file-io, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In metro, the codes like following will [throw exception](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/46a3088d-8420-485b-8697-8b2dda0f1f19/):

```
String fileName = @"C:\Test\dd\ccc.jpg";
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fileName);
```

However even if I check everything in capabilities, also File Picker was added and all file types allowed. I still can't access this file, the same exception will be thrown.

Does someone know how to read file in arbitrary file path? Is that possible in metro style application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible. You can get to the Libraries - pictures, documents, videos - and if the user puts that folder into one of those libraries (using Windows Explorer on the desktop side) you're all set. You can even write a desktop exe that will put the folder into the library, but you can't launch that exe yourself or be sure that the user hasn't changed the libraries by hand.

Look up SHCreateItemInKnownFolder for a starting point to the shell APIs for library work. I haven't tried calling those APIs from the Metro side; you can see if they help but my bet is they will not be available. If you don't like the COM interop to the shell APIs you could look at the source code to the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) - I wouldn't want to bundle all of it with a Metro app, but you could copy parts of it to your application.