# Sharing files between metro and desktop app

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have a desktop app which creates files under c:\ProgramData folder on windows 7. (I can't move the files location to document folder.) I want to provide a metro version of this application as well. The metro application should be able to read and write the same files which are created by the desktop version. As I see, metro does not allow this in some obvious way. Is there a way to make that folder available to metro app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 metro application access arbitrary file path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874273/windows-8-metro-application-access-arbitrary-file-path)

Comment: Metro has a limited set of folders it can access.  C:\ProgramData isn't on the list.

Answer (score 2):

Metro applications can't access most of the windows desktop folders.   C:\ProgramData is not one of the allowed locations.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) for a list of the allowed locations and how to get to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can add possibility to 'send' your data to your desktop app from WinRT app. Try to use sharing contract ([check there](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/18/windows-8-the-sharing-contract/) and [there](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782) ) for this. I understand that isn't well solution for this but it is better than nothing.

**EDIT:** This way isn't possible. I've just checked and get message - ***Nothing can be shared from desktop.***

Comment: According to the following link charm contracts don't seem to be available for desktop apps. Am I missing something?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/4f102277-5e10-41a5-9c37-403e6ab9d21c

Comment: I've just checked. You are right. Nothing can be shared from desktop.